# Efficient way of extracting co-occurence values of specific word pairs from Python Counter() results

Tags: python

I am quite new to Python, so I am not sure if there's a simple solution to my problem. I have a large corpus of text split into ~40,000 documents, each in one row (already tokenized so each word in a row is a token). I calculated the co-occurrences for each two-word combination, using the following code:

```
import itertools
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

cooccurrences = []

for tokens in data['tokenized_text']:
    tokens_pairs = itertools.combinations(tokens, 2)
    for pair in tokens_pairs:
        cooccurrences.append(tuple(sorted(pair)))

word_cooccurrence_counter = Counter(cooccurrences)
```

I can calculate the frequency of co-occurence of any two words like this:

```
word_cooccurrence_counter['foo','faa']

[output]: 
124
```

Now I would like to be able to get these results for a specific set of words, over all pairs where they appear. So for instance, for the word 'foo', I'd like to get all the words for which the co-occurrence frequency is more than 0.

I have tried doing this using a loop over all the words in the corpus:

```
outputs = []
# lst is a flat list of all the tokenized words in the corpus

for word in lst:
    get_results = word_cooccurrence_counter['foo', word]
    outputs.append([word, get_results])
```

This works, but because my corpus is so large, it crashes half the time. And at any rate I have a couple hundred words I'd like to do this for (beyond 'foo').

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? For instance, I thought of setting a threshold for the minimum co-occurrence frequency – but then it would still loop through my whole list of words in the corpus (there are thousands).

Any help is really appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to iterate over the entire corpus, only over the `Counter` object (which is inherently smaller):

```
for words_tuple, count in word_cooccurrence_counter.items():
    if 'foo' in words_tuple:
        print(words_tuple, count)
```

Also, your original implementation would have found the counts of `('foo', word)`, but ignore the counts of `(word, 'foo')` (assuming the order does matter). This will find/count both.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. For others using this, a note: I hadn't realised it when I wrote the question, but using this approach means that if a word is repeated within a document, the co-occurence will also be repeated. So if 'foo' co-occurs with 'faa' in exactly one document, but it is repeated 5 times in that document, the co-occurence will be recorded as 5. So you'll need to account for this somehow (e.g. in preprocessing).

Answer (score 2):

Use `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(..., ngram_range=(1,2))`, that's precisely what it does. And it prunes your wordlist as-it-goes if you use `min_df` and `max_features` parameters. Also, make sure to pass a (customized) list of stopwords to avoid wasting effort counting them.

`Counter` is not for serious NLP use. Don't reinvent the wheel.